# Configure a Spring bean callback on server startup?

Tags: spring, hibernate

I want my server to do some database cleanup on startup. I tried adding a @PostConstruct method to a service to do this, however @Transactional doesn't work there. Any changes I make aren't being persisted. How can I get this done? Can I create a new bean with specific callbacks on it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just call another transactional resource in @PostConstruct which does the work, because injection is done then. So `DbPopulator` can use `UserService` and whatsoever in its `@PostConstruct` and everything is transactional and nicely separated again. Singleton beans are constructed at startup afaik, so no additonal setup required.

Comment: true it seems to be just a proxy problem

Comment: This didn't work if I created another @Transactional function in the same service and called that. Are you saying I will need to call another service to do the transactional part?

Comment: Yes this is true. Calling another method on the same service via this, bypasses the proxy. You need to call another service. Maybe injecting FooService into FooService helps in that matter (it does in java ee, I don't know if it works with Spring).

Comment: Thanks, I created another component with the @PostConstruct in it, and that component calls my service. Seems to work.